# Mathematics vs. physics notation for differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, notation, mathematical-physics

Is there a reference out there somewhere that gives a *dictionary* of *mathematician's* notation vs. *physicist's* notation in differential geometry?

For example,

$$\nabla_v ( f \mathbf{X} ) = (vf) \mathbf{X} + f \nabla_v \mathbf{X}, $$

as opposed to

$$v^\mu \nabla_\mu (f X^\nu ) = (v^\mu \partial_\mu f) X^\nu + f v^\mu \nabla_\mu X^\nu $$

for covariant derivatives / connections on smooth manifolds. Of course, assuming that we can use local coordinates.

Comment: "Of course, assuming that we can use local coordinates." Why would you not be able to use local coordinates?

Comment: I have no idea what the $n$ is doing in your first equation. :) The second equation is also mathematicians' notation if one works in coordinates (using Einstein summation convention, of course).

Comment: There was such a thing drifting around Berkeley in about 1981...a short LaTeX document...but I haven't seen it in about 35 years. It was meant to help gauge-theory folks from physics talk with mathematicians and vice versa.

Comment: Well, one often jokes that differential geometry is the study of things invariant under change of notation.  So there isn't really even a dictionary of notation among the mathematicians!

Comment: @s.harp Hey, better safe than sorry :)

Comment: @TedShifrin It's a point $n$, didn't want to overexplain an example. Yeah, some mathematicians do use the second notation, but I feel like it's more welcome among physicists.

Comment: Then the point $n$ needs to be on the left side too. There's no evidence of $n$ in the “physicists' equation,” so let's forget it.

Comment: @TedShifrin Fair enough.